# split the arraylist and return as string upto the length of arraylist

Tags: c#, autocomplete, arraylist, n-tier-architecture

```
autoComplete1.ServiceMethod = objdpt.LoadDpt(prefix);
```

`aspx.cs` file code.. calling `loaddpt` function

```
public string LoadDpt(string prefixtext)
{
    //Functionality : AutoComplete The DepartmentName
    ArrayList  arlSample = new ArrayList();
    arlSample = objDataAccess.GetSingleColumn("QRY_DeptName", prefixtext);
    return arlSample;
    //string[] strArray = arlSample.ToArray(typeof(string)) as string[];   
}
```

above is bll file code. calling `getsinglecolum` function

```
public ArrayList GetSingleColumn(string strQuery, params object[] objValueList)
{ 
    ArrayList arlData = new ArrayList();
    try
    {
        string strQry;
        strQry = ReadXmlvalue(strQuery, objValueList);
        cmdHrm = new OleDbCommand();
        cmdHrm.Connection = conHrmDb;
        if (conHrmDb.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            conHrmDb.Open();
        cmdHrm.CommandText = strQry;
        drdHrm = cmdHrm.ExecuteReader();

        while (drdHrm.Read())
        {
            arlData.Add(drdHrm.ToString());
        }
        return arlData;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (conHrmDb.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            conHrmDb.Close();
    }
}
```

above is dal file code.
i want to return the string to `aspx.cs` file..help plz

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the ArrayList to a string array you can use:

```
 IEnumerable<string> strings = arlSample.Cast<string>();
 string[] result = strings.ToArray();
```

If you want to concatenate all the elements so you can return one string you should use:

```
 string resultString = String.Concat(strings);
```

Comment: i dont want to concatenate..but each string has to return separately

Comment: Then return the result string array. That will return each string separately. You can't return multiple results from one function except when you use something like an iterator with 'yield'.

Comment: but the function call needs only string not string array..thats the problem am facing

Comment: You can't return multiple strings for a function that expects only one string. What exactly are you trying to do? Pleace edit your post with more information.